# How to setup, and use, Google C++ Test in Borland Development Studio 2006?

Tags: c++, testing, c++builder

I've looked through the Google C++ Testing documentation, and whilst it makes reference to Borland C++ saying that it is supported, there doesn't appear to be any specific, and clear, instructions on how to get it working.

First, I need to know how to build the `lib` file. I can do this is Visual Studio C++, but haven't worked out how to do this in BDS2006 yet.

Importing the lib file (or dll?) into BDS and using the methods should be simple enough I guess once step one is complete.

However, I ran a test importing the `gtestd.lib` file from VS into BDS and adding `#include "gtest/gtest.h"` to my sources, but the compiler rejected it with lots of (alleged) errors in the header files.

eg

```
[C++ Error] gtest-tuple.h(388): E2437 'typename' should be followed by a qualified, dependent type name
```

Which referred to:

```
explicit tuple(GTEST_BY_REF_(T0) f0) : f0_(f0) {}
```

I'm guessing that I may need to adjust some project settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a problem that old C++ Builder compilers don't properly implement SFINAE.
So you properly need another compiler. Not easy I know.